# type of pointer returned by tcl_createinterp()

Tags: c++, tcl

I am evaluating tcl commands in c++ and for that I am creating tcl interpreter in c++ using Tcl_createInterp() API.
What I understand is interpreter is a program which runs the commands for TCL. 
But I have one silly question. The pointer returned by Tcl_createInterp() points to what?
does it point to a program location for TCL in memory?
I know this question has nothing to do with my project but I am just trying to understand the back-end.

Comment: If a function is called `createInterp()`, I'd expect the pointer it returns to point to an **interpreter** data structure, however it be realized.

Comment: You should treat the return value of `Tcl_CreateInterp()` as opaque value. Did you ever ask to what `FILE *` points to?

Answer (score 0):

It's a pointer to an internal implementation structure that defines a script evaluation context. It's that context which any “global” values in the script are global with respect to, and which defines the mapping of command names to implementations. It's implementation (plus the things it depends on) is the vast majority of what the Tcl library does.

In C++ terms, treat it as if you're dealing with something that's using the [PIMPL pattern](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PimplIdiom). Since 8.6, there's *no* user-accessible fields in what it points to at all (and you're not really supposed to look inside with earlier versions either).